# How to insert a row, but on duplicate; update it instead?

Tags: mysql, insert

I have a table which contains the items the users of my game owns. If a user buys a new item, it should be inserted, but if he already got it, it should be increased instead.

I understand I can use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, but I don't understand how in my problem.

The `item_id` isn't unique, because many players can own the same weapon (ie. a longsword). The `user_id` isn't unique either, because a player can own many items.

So, my question is how to make the query `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT` if a row containing both the `user_id` and `item_id` already exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not what the "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" will do for you.  If it were me, I would attempt the insert.  If it failed, check why (you're checking for errors already, right?).  If it's because of a duplicate key, do your update.  If the error is for some other reason, then handle that appropriately.

Comment: The duplicate is detected based on the primary key constraint, or any other unique constraint/index on the table.

The thing is, it sounds like you have a "quantity" column.  If you insert a row, you want the quantity to be 1.  If you're updating because the player already has 1, then you want the quantity to be incremented...  ON DUP KEY UPDATE will only make the existing row match what you wanted to insert.  You'll have to do as I suggest, or look for the presense of the row first.  I prefer my way.

Comment: BTW, my reasoning:  Checking first always takes two queries.  Trying, and checking the result, only takes two queries if it's a dup.

Comment: Sorry, I removed my comment after your edited. Okay, I just wondered if it was possible to do this with only using one query.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old but none of the answers are correct.

You need a `PRIMARY or UNIQUE` index on user_id and item_id (both columns in one index).

Then you can use `"INSERT INTO ... VALUES ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count=count+1"` no problem.

This is `EXACTLY` what `ON DUPLICATE UPDATE` will do for you.

Comment: Old, and I came in 2015 for the answer - thanks, used with UNIQUE, worked.

Answer (score 2):

You do want **ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE**.  It looks for the Primary Key of the table, and if it exists, updates all the other rows.

So your table has a primary key of (userid, itemid) and the following values:

```
userid   itemid   strength
4        5        6
```

And you want to bump it to strength=9, use this:

```
INSERT INTO table ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE VALUES(4,5,9)
```

It will insert a row with 4,5,9 if it doesn't exist, and will update strength to 9 *on the row with primary key (4,5)* if it does exist.  It won't update any other rows (e.g. rows with userid4 but itemid 10 or itemid 5 but userid 70) because they don't match the whole PK.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like the following (assumes your user id is in the variable UserID and item ID is in item_ID) :

```
  SELECT
    @rowCount := COUNT(*)
  FROM
    table
  WHERE
     user_id = UserID
     AND item_id = ItemID;


   IF (@rowCount > 0) THEN

   ... do update

   ELSE
    ... do insert

   END IF;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like

```
UPDATE TABLE
set COL = 'BLAH BLAH'
where ITEM_ID = @itemid AND USER_ID = @userid

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TABLE (col...)
    VALUES (vals...
END
```