# Inserting row while avoiding duplicated in MySQL

Tags: mysql, insert, duplicates

```
$sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO product (reference, description, price, created_at, updated_at)
VALUES ('{$sku}', '{$description}', '{$price}', '{$created_at}', '{$updated_at}')";
```

.. keeps on creating new rows because of the incrementing `id` column, how do I make `SKU` unique so it checks if `SKU` value exists, then `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT`.

Comment: Add a unique index on the `reference` column with `ALTER TABLE ` or `CREATE INDEX`.

Comment: You may be able to use [INSERT..ON DUPLICATE KEY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). The SQL equivalent would be `MERGE` but that does not seem to be supported within MySQL.

Comment: @AnthonyForloney If he doesn't have a unique index, `ON DUPLICATE KEY` won't do anything.

Comment: Yes, I'm reading it but don't quite understand how to use. Just learning MySQL. :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575310/how-to-insert-a-row-but-on-duplicate-update-it-instead

Comment: @Ismaestro All those answers assume you already have a unique key. They don't say how to create the unique key in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a unique key on the column you don't want to allow duplicates of:

```
ALTER TABLE product ADD UNIQUE KEY (reference);
```

Once you've done this, you can use the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause to update the row instead of ignoring the `INSERT`.

```
INSERT INTO product (reference, description, price, created_at, updated_at)
VALUES ('{$sku}', '{$description}', '{$price}', '{$created_at}', '{$updated_at}')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    description = VALUES(description),
    price = VALUES(price),
    created_at = VALUES(created_at),
    updated_at = VALUES(updated_at)
```

Using `VALUES` in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause picks up the values that would have been assigned during an `INSERT` of a new row.

Comment: This is done just once? or every time I make a query?

Comment: Just once. Indexes are part of the schema.

Comment: You need the unique key plus [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Comment: Strange issue. Although the `$conn->query($sql) === TRUE)` passes and it reports `row created successfully` but I don't see many entries in the DB. One for example is `0213A5` which isn't in the DB. I'm also `mysqli_real_escape_string` the strings incase that's causing the error.

Comment: Figured it. There was a warning: `mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given` so I changed it to `$description_safe = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $description);`